# Como criar um teste unitário utilizando o mockito em uma lista de objetos

Tags: junit, mockito

Eu sei exatamente o que preciso mockar em relação aos dados do objeto, porém não tenho ideia como deve implementar um teste quando se trata de uma lista de objetos, eu só preciso de um exemplo, alguém poderia somente me mostrar um exemplo pelo qual eu possa ter uma breve noção de como implementar o meu teste unitário em relação ao contexto desse método abaixo que está na classe de serviços?

```
@Service
@TransactionalEntrada
public class IndicioService extends AbstractService<IndicioEntity, IndicioDAO> {

    @Autowired
    private HistoricoSituacaoService historicoSituacaoService;

    @Autowired
    private IndicioDAO indicioDAO;

    @Override
    protected IndicioDAO getDao() {

        return indicioDAO;
    }

 public void importarIndicios(List<IndicioEntity> indicios,
            UsuarioLogadoExterno usuarioLogado) throws PrincipalException {

        for (final IndicioEntity indicio : indicios) {
            indicio.setDataUltimaMovimentacao(getDataAtual());
            final SituacaoIndicioEntity situacao = new SituacaoIndicioEntity();
            situacao.setCodigo(1);
            indicio.setSituacaoAtual(situacao);
            this.inserir(indicio);// salvar indicios

            final HistoricoSituacaoEntity historicoSituacao =
                    new HistoricoSituacaoEntity();

            historicoSituacao.setCodigoUsuario(usuarioLogado.getCodigo());
            historicoSituacao.setCodigoIndicio(indicio.getCodigo());
            historicoSituacao.setCodigoSituacaoIndicio(
                    indicio.getSituacaoAtual().getCodigo());
            historicoSituacao
                    .setDataMovimentacao(indicio.getDataUltimaMovimentacao());

            historicoSituacaoService.inserir(historicoSituacao);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu contexto de teste, a coisa mais importante a se fazer é validar se as propriedades do `HistoricoSituacaoEntity` criado dentro do método estão de acordo com o que você espera, e se o `historicoSituacaoService.inserir` foi chamado conforme o esperado.

Um exemplo de como ficaria este teste:

```
public class IndicioServiceTest {

    @Test
    public void importarIndicios() {
        ArgumentCaptor<HistoricoSituacaoEntity> historicoCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(HistoricoSituacaoEntity.class); // Utilizado para capturar o valor passado à um método

        List<IndicioEntity> indicios = ... (Criar seus indicios manualmente);
        UsuarioLogadoExterno usuarioLogado = ... (Criar seu usuario logado manualmente);

        service.importarIndicios(indicios, usuarioLogado); // Chamada para sua função

        Mockito.verify(historicoSituacaoService).inserir(historicoCaptor.capture()); // Validação da chamada do serviço e captura do histórico criado

        HistoricoSituacaoEntity historicoCriado = historicoCaptor.getValue();

        Assert.assertEquals(usuarioLogado.getCodigo(), historicoCriado.getCodigoUsuario());
        ... Validar outras propriedades do indicio e usuário que devem estar no histórico que foi criado dentro do método ...
    }

    @Mock
    private IndicioDAO indicioDao;

    @Mock
    private HistoricoSituacaoService historicoSituacaoService;

    @InjectMocks
    private IndicioService service;
}
```

Sugiro você sempre pensar na parte mais importante do seu teste, **no que você realmente precisa testar**. É mais importante você validar (fazer asserts) e verificar o que realmente precisa do que apenas escrever um teste só por escrever.

Documentação do [ArgumentCaptor](http://site.mockito.org/javadoc/current/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html)

Comment: Eu entendi perfeitamente sua sugestão, eu coloquei seu código e me esbarrei em duas coisas , a linha 5 a sintaxe **for** não foi reconhecida como valida, e na linha 16 do código o método **assertEquals** o eclipse disse que aceita na assinatura do método um int e em seguida um integer, talvés eu deva usar um outro método. porque o retorno é um integer e em seguida um outro integer.

Comment: Peço desculpas, fiz o código de cabeça :) o correto é `ArgumentCaptor.forClass`